# creating a dynamic key using the sender's name

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm trying to store NSUserDefault information to keep track of all the values in a whole bunch of UITextField objects.

Even though the view controller is aware of every single instance of these text fields, i'm trying to avoid creating a key for every one of them, such as:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    NSString *curKey=[NSString string];
    if (textField == nameField) {
        curKey=@"nameField";
    }else if (textField == dateField){
        curKey=@"dateField";
    }else if (textField == cityField){
        curKey=@"cityField";
    }else if (textField == ageField){
        curKey=@"ageField";
    }else if (textField == colorField){
        curKey=@"colorField";
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:curKey];

    return YES;
}
```

Is there no way to determine what the instance's name is to dynamically create the keys?
I also tried using IB's "User Defined Runtime Attributes" (as myName) to make the UITextField aware of it's name:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textField.text forKey:[textField valueForKey:@"myName"]];
```

Using int Tags doesn't make for interesting keys...

I don't remember any other objects (in any language) having instances aware of what other's call them, but I'm fishing for ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to initialize curKey to `[NSString string]`; you're just setting it to a dead value then assigning the pointer to a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have 2 options.

If you have a fixed number of textField, you should create a property for each of them (you can connect it via an outlet form the interface builder) and do

```
if (textField == self.nameField)
```

---

The second approach is similar, but for a huge number of textfields/or dynamic number of textfields:

add each textfield to a dictionary with a key like `@"cityField"`

use `NSString *key =[[dictionary allKeysForObject:textFiled] objectAtIndex:0];`

---

Many other similar approaches are possible: 
Keep keys and textfield in separated array. Use

```
NSUInteger index =[fields indexForObject:textField];
NSString *key = [keys objectAtIndex:indey];
```

Comment: and no: you can't ask for the variable's name.